# using IPL_DEPTH_32f in Opencv

Tags: c, opencv

what Does this mean "IPL_DEPTH_32F " in openCv ?
and what will happened in the picture  when we convert it to  IPL_DEPTH_8U ?

from where I know the image is "IPL_DEPTH_32F" or "IPL_DEPTH_8U" , when I use this function `CVCreateImage`  ?!

Answer (score 3):

Pixel depth in `opencv` is specified as:

```
IPL_DEPTH_<bit_depth>(S|U|F)
```

Where S is signed, U is unsigned and F is float.

`IPL_DEPTH_32F` means per channel per pixel is stored as 32 bit floating point number.

When you convert it to `IPL_DEPTH_8U`, number of values that can be represented by each pixel per channel decreases and thus quality will decrease and the size of image buffer would be smaller.